# How can I find the MS Access version and/or dll name used for a FireDac connection?

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a FireDac connection to an Microsoft Access database. I'm configuring the Parms on the connection like so:

```
Connection.Params.Add('DriverID=MSAcc');
Connection.Params.Add('Database=' + FDatabasePath);
Connection.Connected := true;
```

Generally this works great.  However, in some cases an old MS Access driver installed.  We would like to detect that situation and alert the user so they can install a new driver.

**How can I get the driver version, or at least the VendorLib name, that FireDac found and used to make the connection?**

I know I can specify a VendorLib on a Phys Connection Link prior the opening my connection.  I don't want to do that.  I want FireDac to go through it's process to find and use the most relevant driver on the system.  However, once that is done I would like to know what driver it ended up using.

I tried creating a TFDPhysMSAccessDriverLink after the connection was open hoping that the ActualDriverId or VendorLib properties would be set.  But ActualDriverId is MsAcc and VendorLib is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Get version of the driver

You can get the driver version in ordinal form by the [**DriverVersion**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper.TODBCConnection.DriverVersion) property, or as a string (which can include also driver description) by the [**DRIVER_VER**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper.TODBCConnection.DRIVER_VER) property. The queried [**SQL_DRIVER_VER**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetinfo-function#information-type-descriptions) info type is in ODBC API described like:

> **SQL_DRIVER_VER (ODBC 1.0)**
>
> A character string with the version of the driver and optionally, a
>   description of the driver. At a minimum, the version is of the form ##.##.####, where the first two digits are the major version, the next two digits are the minor version, and the last four digits are the
>   release version.

With FireDAC you can get it this way:

```
uses
  FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DriverVerStr: string;
  DriverVerInt: TFDVersion;
  ODBCConnection: TODBCConnection;
begin
  ODBCConnection := TObject(FDConnection.CliObj) as TODBCConnection;

  DriverVerStr := ODBCConnection.DRIVER_VER;
  DriverVerInt := ODBCConnection.DriverVersion;

  Memo.Lines.Add(Format('DriverVerStr: %s', [DriverVerStr]));
  Memo.Lines.Add(Format('DriverVerInt: %d', [DriverVerInt]));
end;
```

### 2. Get version of ODBC that the driver supports

To get ODBC version supported by the used driver you can use the [**DriverODBCVersion**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper.TODBCConnection.DriverODBCVersion) property to obtain ordinal value, or [**DRIVER_ODBC_VER**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper.TODBCConnection.DRIVER_ODBC_VER) to get a string value. Queried [**SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetinfo-function#information-type-descriptions) data type info is described like:

> **SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER (ODBC 2.0)**
>
> A character string with the version of ODBC that the driver supports.
>   The version is of the form ##.##, where the first two digits are the
>   major version and the next two digits are the minor version.
>   SQL_SPEC_MAJOR and SQL_SPEC_MINOR define the major and minor version
>   numbers. For the version of ODBC described in this manual, these are 3
>   and 0, and the driver should return "03.00".

With FireDAC you can get it this way:

```
uses
  FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ODBCVerStr: string;
  ODBCVerInt: TFDVersion;
  ODBCConnection: TODBCConnection;
begin
  ODBCConnection := TObject(FDConnection.CliObj) as TODBCConnection;

  ODBCVerStr := ODBCConnection.DRIVER_ODBC_VER;
  ODBCVerInt := ODBCConnection.DriverODBCVersion;

  Memo.Lines.Add(Format('ODBCVerStr: %s', [ODBCVerStr]));
  Memo.Lines.Add(Format('ODBCVerInt: %d', [ODBCVerInt]));
end;
```

### 3. Get version of the DBMS product accessed by the driver

You can get the accessed DBMS product version by the [**DBMS_VER**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper.TODBCConnection.DBMS_VER) property. ODBC API describes the queried [**SQL_DBMS_VER**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetinfo-function#information-type-descriptions) info type as:

> **SQL_DBMS_VER (ODBC 1.0)**
>
> A character string that indicates the version of the DBMS product
>   accessed by the driver. The version is of the form ##.##.####, where
>   the first two digits are the major version, the next two digits are
>   the minor version, and the last four digits are the release version.
>   The driver must render the DBMS product version in this form but can
>   also append the DBMS product-specific version. For example,
>   "04.01.0000 Rdb 4.1".

With FireDAC you can get it this way (there is no property returning parsed ordinal version number, so let's try parsing to ordinal value by ourselves):

```
uses
  FireDAC.Stan.Util, FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DBMSVerStr: string;
  DBMSVerInt: TFDVersion;
  ODBCConnection: TODBCConnection;
begin
  ODBCConnection := TObject(FDConnection.CliObj) as TODBCConnection;

  DBMSVerStr := ODBCConnection.DBMS_VER;
  DBMSVerInt := FDVerStr2Int(DBMSVerStr);

  Memo.Lines.Add(Format('DBMSVerStr: %s', [DBMSVerStr]));
  Memo.Lines.Add(Format('DBMSVerInt: %d', [DBMSVerInt]));
end;
```

### 4. Get FireDAC unified version information

FireDAC provides the [**ClientVersion**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.Intf.IFDPhysConnectionMetadata.ClientVersion) and [**ServerVersion**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.Intf.IFDPhysConnectionMetadata.ServerVersion) properties which are accessible through the [**ConnectionMetaDataIntf**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.ConnectionMetaDataIntf) interface property of the connection object.

For ODBC drivers the [**ClientVersion**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.Intf.IFDPhysConnectionMetadata.ClientVersion) property returns the driver version (described in section 1 here) if the driver is not a single tier driver, DBMS product version otherwise (described in section 3). The [**ServerVersion**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.Intf.IFDPhysConnectionMetadata.ServerVersion) returns always DBMS product version (described in section 3 here) for ODBC drivers.

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Metadata: IFDPhysConnectionMetadata;
begin
  Metadata := FDConnection.ConnectionMetaDataIntf;
  try
    Memo.Lines.Add(Format('ClientVersion: %d', [Metadata.ClientVersion]));
    Memo.Lines.Add(Format('ServerVersion: %d', [Metadata.ServerVersion]));
  finally
    Metadata := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Those properties seem to return the ODBC version that the driver implements - not the version of the driver itself. Right now I can see two dirvers in my ODBC Admin tool for Access.  One is version 10.00.15063, the other is 14.00.7010. When I run your code on my connection I get the following: DRIVER_VER: Microsoft Access database engine 
DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 03.51  
DriverVersion: 0  
DriverODBCVersion: 351000000

Comment: I was hoping that the `DRIVER_VER` will be the CLI version. At least should be. That `DRIVER_ODBC_VER` should report supported ODBC version. Well, badly implemented `SQL_DRIVER_VER` info type in that driver. In that case, hm, maybe check the version of the driver library?

Comment: Updated. I've tried to cover version information you might be interested in. I guess it is the DBMS product information that you are looking for (at least your title says _"How can I find MS Access version"_, sorry I missed that). Why driver version returns for your used driver something else than ODBC API specifies is simply because of wrong implementation (if someone instead of _"At a minimum, the version is of the form ##.##.####"_ returns _"Access database engine"_, is not worth commenting :)

Comment: I'll need to uninstall my old drivers and check some of the version numbers to see what changes. You did give me an idea on where to head though. Because of what Access is returning I am going to use the OdbcConnection.DRIVER_NAME property.  That give me aceodbc.dll.  I can then read the version number from the dll. That is getting me the version I expect to see. Thanks for the detailed post.

Comment: One more question: I can't find a way to check that FDConnection.CliObj really is a TODBCConnection. I'd like to add a check around that cast but I can't seem to see how FireDac keeps track of what it has. Everything else seem to be wrapped up inside interfaces - but I can't get to DRIVER_NAME from any of them.

Comment: That's a driver specific stuff. For different drivers there are different connection objects with driver specific properties (for example PostgreSQL CLI object has just `SERVER_VERSION` (`ServerVersion`) properties related to versioning). So you can e.g. ask if that CLI object `is` of specific type (do not rely on DBMS type because there can be more ways to connect to a single DBMS and in that case the CLI object may differ, e.g. native or ODBC). CLI objects you cannot unify. Let me check the source if there's a unified way to get fully specified path to the used physical driver...

Comment: I was not paying enough attention to what I was doing.  I was trying to use "is" on the pointer.  I needed:   if TObject(FDConnection.CliObj) is TODBCConnection then... Working great now.  Thank you!

Comment: I've extended the post for getting unified version info. But it's not suitable for you (so long the driver returns nonsense when it's queried for `SQL_DRIVER_VER` info type).